# Regex Check that each word starts with a capital letter

Tags: c#, regex

If I have these words

1. ValleyForgeElm
2. valleyforgeElm
3. Valleyforgeelm
4. Valley forge Elm
5. Valley Forge Elm
6. Valley FOrge Elm

In Regex I would want to validate that only number 3 and 5 are valid.
3 is valid because it has no spaces and only 1 upper case in the front.
5 is valid because anywhere there is a space each word starts with an upper case and has no other upper cases.
For example 6 is not valid because Forge has an upper case O in it.

Can this be done with Regex?

Comment: Which application/language/platform/flavor will you be using? `^([\p{Lu}][\p{Ll}]*\s)*[\p{Lu}][\p{Ll}]*$` might do the trick

Comment: C# is the language. This worked thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:\b[A-Z]{1}[a-z]*\b\s?)+$
^                               // Start of string
 (?:                     )+     // Capture the following group one or more times
    \b                          // Word boundary
      [A-Z]{1}                  // Exactly one upper case letter
              [a-z]*            // Zero or more lower case letters
                    \b          // Word boundary
                      \s?       // Zero or one white space character
                           $    // End of string
```

[Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/TKsbMs/1)

Comment: I didn't, but perhaps it's being downvoted because it 1) doesn't support single-character words and 2) might match a trailing space

Comment: I'm not the down voter too. And I think the same than the 1st point of @MathiasR.Jessen : you could support the 1 word letter case replacing the **[a-z]+** with a **[a-z]\***. By the way, nice explanation of your regex. I like the style ;)

Comment: And update the link to regex101. ;)